# Statistically comparing two scatter plots in R

Tags: bioinformatics

I have 2 different data sets (gene expression) where the same samples have been run on different platforms and the data has undergone different types of normalization. I have performed umap dimensional reduction in order to view the data in scatter plots and visualize clusters of samples.

My question is: what would be the best approach for statistically comparing the two scatter plots in order to compare how well the normalization has performed? I do have more than 1 type of normalization (and therefore more scatter plots) that I would like to compare to the reference data shown below (Dataset 1/Scatter plot 1)

```
Dataset 1:
                   [,1]      [,2]
i036_003_3m1  7.0449790  4.164416
i036_005_1t1  3.8745112 -5.197640
i036_009_1m1  3.4761843 -4.680989
i036_011_1t1 -0.0950184 -2.227089
i036_012_1m1  8.2278333  3.943403
i036_013_0t1 -5.2064330  2.746905
i036_014_2t1 -5.3619309 -6.267813
i036_015_2t1 -5.9260608  2.554369
i036_017_1t1  2.2610908 -1.512848
i036_018_0t1 -3.3875058 -3.935059
...

Dataset 2:
                   [,1]       [,2]
i036_003_3m1  8.3399352  4.6299334
i036_005_1t1  3.6490480 -4.7500006
i036_009_1m1 -5.9914297  2.0903825
i036_011_1t1  1.0448757 11.4182328
i036_012_1m1  0.9834183  0.8678468
i036_013_0t1  1.5129282 -3.3277251
i036_014_2t1  1.8282211  0.7294145
i036_015_2t1  0.2120513 -3.0281639
i036_017_1t1  3.3461548 -0.3356379
i036_018_0t1  1.5178497 -1.0826521
...
```

[image: Scatter plot 1 - RNAseq data]

[image: Scatter plot 2 - Normalized data]

Any thoughts or suggestions would be great!

Comment: The data tables were not clear - they are just two data.frames with an X and a Y coordinate for each sample.

Comment: What does "compare" mean exactly to you? Probably, you'd do something based on distances.

Comment: I've followed @AllanCameron in recommending this is moved to CrossValidated. However, you need to figure out what it means for you to have a "well-performed normalization". If you have biological replicates, you may want the normalization where the distance between replicates is minimal. You may also want to maximize the distance between your contrast groups. Since this is gene expression, there are actually community-recommended pipelines for normalization, unless your specific platform is something new. For RNA-seq, I'd follow the `DESeq2` recommendations, for microarray, `limma` works well.

Comment: Thank you for you initial responses.
In this specific case, I am examining different methods of cross platform normalization, so I have paired samples that have been run on multiple platforms (RNAseq, affy arrays, custom arrays). I am then examining, for example, how well affy data can be normalized to resemble RNAseq data.
As @Roland mentioned, it would be a distance based measure that I would like to perform. Such as a Euclidean distance distribution, however I cannot find any good examples (code examples) on how to perform these distance calculations between two coordinate data frames.

Comment: Since you seem to have matrices with identical row names, can't you simply do `sqrt(rowSums((m2 - m1)^2))`?

Comment: Thanks! Yes that is a simple approach to get the euclidean distances. What I am wondering is if there is a method of calculating these distances (so difference between reference values and predicted/normalized values) with a measure of statistical significance. Or if perhaps I should be going about this a different way?